# How To Use Multiple Internet Services To Create One File For Faster Upload

Tags: performance, upload, utorrent

I would like to be able to upload by using my IS and "merging" it with another IP/IS to increase my bandwidth primarily my upload. I have been told by my friend whom is a professional programmer it can be done. However, he specializes in program engineering and less on the networking side I was hoping that someone here would be able to provide the necessary language. After which, I will give it to him. To make my intentions clear, I would like to run a seedbox for the purpose of seeding torrent files by getting all my buddies together and using our connections to the internet in a combined fashion controlled by a single server. I understand manipulations will most likely need to be made both client side and server.
Anything you could give me would be greatly appreciated. Thank you. 
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Well torrent is really is what torrent is. If you've got 5 different machines, all seeding the same content, then they'll all use their internet connections to provide whatever is available. So then you say, hey, I want a to drop the file on the seed box, and have the other clients copy out that file and begin to upload it. But wait, that is what torrent does. As long as the other clients are re-seeding, then they will copy the file from the server, and re-seed it out. It sounds to me like this is as easy as: download uTorrent.